# How to plot 3d array in gray scale in matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

Want to plot an array in gray scale image.Here is my array:

```
[[[ 0.27543858  0.30173767 -0.0101363   0.30631673  0.08575112
    0.02205707 -0.15502007  0.11055402 -0.11761152]
  [ 0.23695524  0.19820367 -0.08758862  0.02446048  0.29235974
   -0.11381532 -0.00426369  0.15231356 -0.24601455]]]
```

Its dimension is (1, 2, 9). It should produce two images with 9 values each.
 I have tried this so far:

```
col_size = 1
row_size = 2
index = 0
fig, ax = plt.subplots(row_size, col_size, figsize=(12,8))
for row in range(0,row_size): 
  for col in range(0,col_size):
    ax[row][col].imshow(result_array[:,:,index],cmap='gray')
    index += 1

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
result_array=result_array.reshape(2,3,3)
print(result_array)
print(result_array.shape)

col_size = 2
row_size = 1
filter_index = 0
fig, ax = plt.subplots(row_size, col_size, figsize=(12,8),  squeeze=False)
for row in range(0,row_size): 
  for col in range(0,col_size):
    ax[row][col].imshow(result_array[filter_index,:,:],cmap='gray')
    filter_index += 1

plt.show()
```